# Floating buttons in AG Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid

I want to have a slack-esque hover interaction on my AG Grid table.

There should be buttons which appear positioned absolutely over the row on hover and no column header for them.

I've tried setting absolute position on the `cellRenderer` and marking the column `width: 0` but the Grid itself seems to wrap cells in an absolute position which sets a new positioning context for my cell- my buttons are positioned inside of my 0-width column instead of positioning relative to the entire row

Can I position my buttons relative to the row and hide the header?

Example Code:

```
"use strict";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Core CSS
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css"; // Theme
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";

const columnDefs = [
  { field: "name" },
  {
    colId: "contextMenu",
    headerName: "Context Menu",
    width: 0,
    cellRenderer: () => {
      return (
        <button style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
          I should be position: absolute
        </button>
      );
    },
  },
];

export const App = () => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      menuTabs: ["filterMenuTab"],
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App ag-theme-quartz flex-grow p-2">
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Full Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relative-position-in-ag-grid-g79454?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-45%2C1)